# hiding or removing object attributes

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to figure out how to make a fairly simple little function that displays different images. Im working inside some software that has a canvas which is a div wrapped in a jquery object. So to get an item to display i can do this.

```
var div = $('#blank');
var good = $('#good');
var ok = $('#ok');
var bad = $('#bad');

instance.canvas.append(div);
```

But I cant for the life of me figure out how to remove that value and display another. I tried adding the entire code snippet and setting display of different elements to "none". I have messed around with the remove() methods and empty() but it seems like it clears everything and I am no longer able to retrieve my elements. im just struggling on this one and I appreciate any help.

Comment: add full code to help better way.

Comment: `div.remove()` (or `div.detach()` if you want to reuse it) should work just fine.

Comment: That was very helpful I was not using the remove method properly before, and it did successfully remove the attribute.